# Prove that $\{g_{\alpha\beta}\}$ is a cocycle on $M$ whose associated vector bundle is the tangent bundle $TM$.

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

> Let $\{(U_\alpha, \varphi_\alpha)\}$ be an atlas on a smooth manifold $M$ where $\varphi_\alpha:U_\alpha \to \mathbb{R}^n$, $\varphi_\alpha=(x^1_\alpha,\dots,x^n_\alpha), n = \dim M$. Let $g_{\alpha\beta}:U_\alpha \cap U_\beta  \to \mathrm{GL}(n,\mathbb{R})$ be the map $$(g_{\alpha\beta}(p))_i^h= \frac{\partial x_\alpha^h}{\partial x_\beta^i}(p), \ p \in U_\alpha\cap U_\beta.$$ Prove that $\{g_{\alpha\beta}\}$ is a cocycle on $M$ whose associated vector bundle is the tangent bundle $TM$.

To show that this is a cocycle we have that $$g_{\alpha\alpha}(p) = I$$ since the diagonal terms will be $1$ and all other terms $0$. Also computing $$g_{\alpha\beta}(p)g_{\beta\gamma}(p)$$ gives for the entries of the matrix terms such as $\frac{\partial x^1\alpha}{\partial x^1\beta} \cdot \frac{\partial x^1\beta}{\partial x^1\gamma} + \frac{\partial x^1\alpha}{\partial x^2\beta} \cdot \frac{\partial x^2\beta}{\partial x^1\gamma} = \frac{\partial x^1\alpha}{\partial x^1\gamma}$  in a $2\times 2$ case due to the chain rule and this generalizes easily to the $n\times n$ case.

So $\{g_{\alpha\beta}\}$ is a cocycle, but how do I prove that it's the one associated to the tangent bundle? If $\pi: TM\to M$ is the tangent bundle of $M$ with local trivializations $\Phi_\alpha:\pi^{-1}(U_\alpha) \to U_\alpha \times \mathbb{R}^n$ and $\Phi_\beta:\pi^{-1}(U_\beta) \to U_\beta \times \mathbb{R}^n$, then I think I would want to show that $$\Phi_\alpha \circ \Phi_{\beta}^{-1}:U_\beta \times \mathbb{R}^n \to U_\alpha \times \mathbb{R}^n$$ given by $$(p,v)\mapsto (p,g_{\alpha\beta}(p)\cdot v).$$

Now computing these transition functions actually for the tangent bundle I get that for the trivializations $\Phi_\alpha:\pi^{-1}(U_\alpha) \to U_\alpha \times \mathbb{R}^n$ and $\Phi_\beta:\pi^{-1}(U_\beta) \to U_\beta \times \mathbb{R}^n$ we have $$\Phi^{-1}_\beta(p,v^1,\dots,v^n) = \left(p, \sum_i v^i\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i_\beta}\right) = \left(p, \sum_{i,j} v^i\frac{\partial x^j_\alpha}{\partial x^i_\beta} \frac{\partial}{\partial x^j_\alpha}\right)$$ on $U_\alpha \cap U_\beta$. So $$\Phi_\alpha \circ \Phi^{-1}_\beta(p,v^1,\dots,v^n) = \left(p, \sum_{i} 
v^i\frac{\partial x^1_\alpha}{\partial x_\beta^i}, \dots \sum_{i} 
v^i\frac{\partial x^n_\alpha}{\partial x_\beta^i} \right)$$ but I don't know whether $$\sum_{i} 
v^i\frac{\partial x^1_\alpha}{\partial x_\beta^i}, \dots \sum_{i} 
v^i\frac{\partial x^n_\alpha}{\partial x_\beta^i}  = g_{\alpha\beta}(p)\cdot v?$$

Comment: Aren't you missing a "$\beta$" in your definition of $g_{\alpha\beta}$? Shouldn't it be $(g_{\alpha\beta}(p))_i^h=\frac{\partial x_\alpha^h}{\partial x_\beta^i}(p)$?

Comment: Then you have that $(g_{\alpha\beta}\cdot v)_k=(g_{\alpha\beta})_i^k\cdot v^i$

Comment: You are right that was a typo. Can you elaborate little bit on your second comment? @YgorArthur

Comment: I just used the multiplication of matrix by vector. The k-th coordinate of the vector $g_{\alpha\beta}(p)\cdot v$ will be the product of the k-th line of the matrix $g_{\alpha\beta}(p)$ by the correspondent coordinate of the vector $v$. So, the first coordinate will be $\sum_i g_{\alpha \beta}_i ^1(p) v^i $ .